# Matching 2 segments but not 3 segments path in Intent Filter / PatternMatcher.PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB

Tags: android, intentfilter

I'm having a problem where I need to filter out "longer" path to not be captured by `intent filter`.

As printed out in the code below,

```
    PatternMatcher pm = new PatternMatcher("/..*/..*", PatternMatcher.PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB);
    Boolean b = pm.match("/segment/segment");
    Boolean c = pm.match("/segment/segment/segment");

    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage(b.toString() + ',' + c.toString());
```

It shows `true,true` as the result.

Is there any way to make the result as `true,false`?
Changing the regex to `/..*/..*/` and url to `/segment/segment/` is impossible.

Thank you. I appreciate discussions

Comment: you want return true when only 2 times there are segment ?

Comment: if 1,3 or 4 or more It will return false you want ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The text are not necessarily `segment`

Answer (score 1):

```
^([/][A-Za-z0-9\s!@#$%^&()';{}\[\]=+\-_~`.\\]+){2}
```

You can use this regular expression to make the result as `true, false` if 
 there is one, three more segments

[View Explanation](https://regexr.com/3memc)

Comment: `PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB` does not have this regex options.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PatternMatcher.html#PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB